# Pusher Svelte AuthError on a presence channel

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, pusher, pusher-js

I'm trying to get pusher presenceschannels working using Svelte.

Here's my client code:

```
this._presenceChannel = this._pusher.subscribe('presence-' + this._channelName);
this._presenceChannel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
this._presenceChannel.bind("pusher:subscription_error", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And my server code for the auth endpoint:

```
export async function POST({request}) {
  const pusher = getPusher();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(await request.text());
  const socketId = params.get('socket_id');
  const user = {
    id: "1",
    user_info: {
      name: "User 1",
    },
  };
  const authResponse = pusher.authenticateUser(socketId, user);
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(authResponse));
}
```

I can see the network request from the client hitting `/pusher/auth` and it responds with a 200 and a body of:

```
{"auth":"...token...","user_data":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"User 1\"}}"}
```

Then the client callback for "pusher:subscription_error" triggers with:

```
{type: 'AuthError', error: undefined}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was confusing ["user authentication"](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/) and ["user authorization"](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/) in Pusher.

What worked was first having the "user authenticate". The client for this was:

```
this._pusher.signin();
```

Which calls `/pusher/user-auth` on the server. The interface for that call was the function I had written in my original question, calling `pusher.authenticateUser`.

Then, when the client subscribes to the channel, this calls `/pusher/auth` which is similar, but requires a call to `pusher.authorizeChannel`.